# Nodemcu Exception (9) problem because of serial communication

Tags: serial-port, communication, esp8266, nodemcu

I have an UI and a mainboard. They are communicated with UART protocol. I added a basic code to my mainboard to send "ADC1=xxxx ADC2=yyyy" data. I want to catch only this data from my mainboard but there are countless values which is sent from UI->MB or MB->UI. As a short ı want to catch only "ADC1=xxxx ADC2=yyyy" as xxxx and yyyy integers or strings and able to write it an basic html page in nodemcu with below code.

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>

int incomingByte = 0;
char deneme[] = "";
const char *delp;
const char *delp2;
/*Put your SSID & Password*/
const char* ssid = "ssid";  // Enter SSID here
const char* password = "pass";  //Enter Password here
ESP8266WebServer server(80);
float Temperature;
float Humidity;
 
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(100);
  Serial.println("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  //connect to your local wi-fi network
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  //check wi-fi is connected to wi-fi network
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected..!");
  Serial.print("Got IP: ");  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  server.on("/", handle_OnConnect);
  server.onNotFound(handle_NotFound);

  server.begin();
  Serial.println("HTTP server started");

}
void loop() {

  if (Serial.available()) // now we have at least one character in the Serial input buffer
  {

String incomingStr = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
incomingStr.toCharArray(deneme,32);
 Serial.println(deneme);
 delp = strtok (deneme,"-");
 delp2 = strtok (NULL,"-");
 Serial.println(delp);
 Serial.println(delp2);

 }
server.handleClient();
 
delay(500);

}

void handle_OnConnect() {
  server.send(200, "text/html", SendHTML(Temperature,Humidity)); 
}

void handle_NotFound(){
  server.send(404, "text/plain", "Not found");
}

String SendHTML(float Temperaturestat,float Humiditystat){
  String ptr = "<!DOCTYPE html> <html>\n";
  ptr +="<head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no\">\n";
  ptr +="<title>ESP8266 Weather Report</title>\n";
  ptr +="<style>html { font-family: Helvetica; display: inline-block; margin: 0px auto; text-align: center;}\n";
  ptr +="body{margin-top: 50px;} h1 {color: #444444;margin: 50px auto 30px;}\n";
  ptr +="p {font-size: 24px;color: #444444;margin-bottom: 10px;}\n";
  ptr +="</style>\n";
  ptr +="<script>\n"; 
  ptr +="setInterval(loadDoc,200);\n";
  ptr +="function loadDoc() {\n";
  ptr +="var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();\n";
  ptr +="xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {\n";
  ptr +="if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {\n";
  ptr +="document.getElementById(\"webpage\").innerHTML =this.responseText}\n";
  ptr +="};\n";
  ptr +="xhttp.open(\"GET\", \"/\", true);\n";
  ptr +="xhttp.send();\n";
  ptr +="}\n";
  ptr +="</script>\n";
  ptr +="</head>\n";
  ptr +="<body>\n";
  ptr +="<div id=\"webpage\">\n";
  ptr +="<h1>ESP8266 NodeMCU Weather Report</h1>\n";
  
  ptr +="<p>Temperature: ";
  ptr +=delp;
  ptr +=" NTC</p>";
  ptr +="<p>Humidity: ";
  ptr +=delp2;
  ptr +=" Heatsink</p>";
  
  ptr +="</div>\n";
  ptr +="</body>\n";
  ptr +="</html>\n";
  return ptr;
}
```

Result of code is an disappointment, ı get error which is named as exception(9). I am not sure what is the problem.
For me, possible reasons;

- There too much values written to serial port,that can be a reason to collapse
- Maybe as code which ı wrote
  What should ı do my friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's problem with

```
char deneme[] = "";
```

also whith use of strtok.
I change declaration and remove blocking delay in loop : try this code : (I assume you receive "0xFF S ? ADC1=1189 ADC2=1508 S ? 0xFF S ?" in serial buffer)

EDIT: enhanced analyse of received data : must use strtok_r as you need two level of token search in array.

```
        //char deneme[] = ""; remove this line
        unsigned long tw;
        
void loop() {
  if (millis() - tw > 500) {  //read serial each 0.5 sec
    if (Serial.available()) // now we have at least one character in the Serial input buffer
    {
      String incomingStr = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
      //I test this with
      //String incomingStr = "0xFF S ? ADC1=1189 ADC2=1508 S ? 0xFF S ?";

      if (incomingStr.indexOf("ADC1") > -1 || incomingStr.indexOf("ADC2") > -1) {  //if serial data contains ADC1 or ADC2
        char deneme[incomingStr.length() + 1];
        incomingStr.toCharArray(deneme, incomingStr.length() + 1);
        Serial.println(deneme);           //return "0xFF S ? ADC1=1189 ADC2=1508 S ? 0xFF S ?"
        //use strtok_r function as we use two instance nested
        //create contexts for strtok_r function 
        char* t1 = deneme; //must assign any value, char* t1; alone fail to compile
        char* t2 = deneme; //idem

        char* token = strtok_r (deneme, " ", &t1);   //return "0xFF", "S", "ADC1=1189", etc...
        while ( token != NULL ) {
          char* token2 = strtok_r(token, "=", &t2);    //return null,null,null,ADC1,ADC2 etc...
          if (token2 != NULL ) {
            if (String(token2) == "ADC1") delp = strtok_r (NULL, "=", &t2); //return 1189
            if (String(token2) == "ADC2") delp2 = strtok_r (NULL, "=", &t2); //return 1508
          }
          token = strtok_r ( NULL, " ", &t1);
        }
        Serial.print("delp = ");Serial.println(delp);
        Serial.print("delp2 = ");Serial.println(delp2);
        tw = millis();
      }
    }
    //scan http requests each loop
    server.handleClient();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code sir, but lots of value return empty with the code. Because of my other inputs like,   
  sprintf(data2,"S      ? \r\n");
  sprintf(data3,"0xFF       \r\n");
  sprintf(data4,"S      ?\r\n");

Comment: I think you did not understand the meaning of my answer: I do not want to write the code for you but help you adjust the basic problems. Is your problem of values received as Null resolved? If not I guarantee you that it comes from the receipt data, not from their interpretation. For the rest it would be better to open a new, more precise question in my opinion. I don't see anything about your Sprintf problems in the current question.

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding, thank you so much for your help. Yes, ıt does not give me exception(9) error but, I can not read values barely  with your code. my inputs are crowded, and the code can not filter only "ADC1=xxxx ADC2=yyyy" my other inputs make hard the serial readings. In below what ı sent from stm32.  your code can not filter barely "ADC1=xxxx ADC2=yyyy"
0xFF
S      ?
ADC1=1189 ADC2=1508
S      ?
0xFF
S      ?

Comment: OK I updated answer to filter received data.

Comment: Countless thank you for your help Sir.  That is awesomely work on my project. The last part of my project sending delp and delp2 to my html page, but ı had some problem with data type on html page. Delp and delp2 does not show the integer value in html page. It show strange caracters. I turn data type to int, string but ı could not solve the problem. I asked as new question in this form but, ı could get a answer. What do you offer me for your awesome solution. Delp and delp2 can not be appear as integer or string in html page on line, ptr +=String(delp);

Comment: No problem : I will try your code tomorrow and see what the problem.